# Angular 5 router doesn't match when query params added

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

```
I have Angular 5 routes config like this: 
const loginRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RegistationComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'sign-in', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'sign-in', component: SigninComponent },
      { path: 'sign-up', pathMatch: 'prefix', component: SignupComponent },
      { path: 'twofactor', component: TwofactorComponent },
    ]
  }
];
```

It works well if I browse the exact route, but when I added the query params, says:

http://localhost:4200/login/reg/sign-up?inviteCode=b8f496ca68a37c174459

it will redirect back to `sign-in` route. How do I fix this?

Comment: `{ path: 'sign-up', pathMatch: 'full', component: SignupComponent },` ?? why do you havbe it as `prefix`?

Comment: I thought full means need to match the whole url, anyway I changed to full it also redirects to sign-in

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] of this issue ? Seems fine to me ...

Comment: @trichetriche It only happens on authentication page for me, I will try to reproduce in a minimal version

Comment: Might be a useless question, but the 'login/reg/', where do you define it ?

Comment: And is your error happening in production mode or in dev mode ?

Comment: @RoadEx the folders are login>registration>signup.  Then the router in the login contains {
        path: 'reg',
        loadChildren: 'app/login/registration/registration.module#RegistrationModule'
      }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the issue, not because of router config, it's due to the auth guard service does the redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your redirect route to something like this:

```
const loginRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RegistationComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'sign-in', component: SigninComponent },
      { path: 'sign-up', pathMatch: 'prefix', component: SignupComponent },
      { path: 'twofactor', component: TwofactorComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'sign-in', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'sign-in', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]
  }
];
```

*UPDATE: added `path:''` route*

Comment: even worse, I cant go to sign-up now

Answer (score 0):

define it like this

```
  { path: 'sign-in/:invitecode', component: SigninComponent },
```